# How to avoid margin above the TextView in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HOME"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't why some margin is coming above it when I run the application. Note that I am using Bottom Navigation Activity.

Here is the screenshot. You can see that there is some margin above HOME.:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To clarify the issue you should include a screenshot highlighting the margin you mention.

Comment: I have added the screenshot. Please answer now.

Comment: How are you using this layout? I tested your XML and appears correctly without any gap at all. But in your screenshot there is an Title Bar, and a bottom navigation bar. So I assume you are nesting it into another different layout? If this is the case, then check the layout holder.

Comment: I am using the bottom navigation activity.

Comment: But what is this layout holder.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say layout folder

Comment: In Andorid a layout can be nested inside another, for example using the "include" tag, As your example XML doesn't contain any navigation bar, I assumed you were nesting it inside a different layout holder using the "include" tag. Can you please share your full layout?

Comment: If I use a "bottom navigation activity", then the top padding is generated by the tag "android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize". Are you using such tag in your main layout?

Comment: I am using bottom navigation activity. Can u tell what files should I share

Comment: In which file android:paddingTop is there, is it in activity_main.xml or in what?

Comment: Share the actual full XML layout, which has everything including the bottom bar. The XML layout in the question presents no problems. So when I test it it works perfect without top padding/margins

Comment: Can u tell in which file android:paddingTop is there, is it in activity_main.xml or in what?

Comment: Yes is in the activity_main.xml, in the actual ConstraintLayout, you will see the tag android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize". This is autogenerated by Android Studio, and you may remove it.

Comment: ok let me check it

Comment: Ok thanks, it solved my problem now there is no margin but android studio should not generate these type of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auto generated your layout with Android Studio Wizard, so in this case a **"bottom navigation activity"**, then Android Studio includes automatically a top padding in the **activity_main.xml** layout, right in the main ConstraintLayout:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Remove such tag to remove the padding.

Comment: Thanks it worked but android studio should not generate these type of tags.

Comment: I request you to please upvote the question as StackOverflow is not allowing me to ask more questions.